# Bijection between subgroups of $\text{Mat}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ and $\mathbb{Z^2}$?

Tags: modular-forms

The following is from the book Modular Forms by W Stein:

[image]

I don't understand the whole sentence from "Note that the set ..." : For example,

1- How is the proving bijection?

2- What does $L=\mathbb{Z}.(a,b) + \mathbb{Z}.(0,d) $ means, i.e. how $.$ is defined? and What does $+$ mean (is it $\oplus$)?

3- How $L$ it is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z^2}$ of index $n$?

Comment: @MattSamuel, exercise 7.5 (5 chapters hereafter!) is about introducing Hermite matrices, no help for none of materials said.

Comment: Is it clear to you that $\mathbb{Z}^2/L$ has $|ad|$ elements (more generally [$|\det(M)|$ elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix)) ? Do you see how right multiplication by $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & k \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ can apply the $\gcd$ algorithm to the bottom row of an integer matrix, thus obtaining an integer matrix with the $c$ entry $= 0$. Do you see how right multiplication by $\gamma \in GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ doesn't change the lattice it represents.

Comment: Yes/no ? ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @reuns, No. With all honestly, I don't know why but I found *all* your explanations (in different questions I've asked), extremely difficult to understand even much more difficult than the books I am reading on MF; esp most of them irrelevant. Sorry but sometimes I think this is (intellectual) prank. For example I've asked the def. of L and you said Z^2/L.. and referred to it as def. of adjugate matrix !!

Comment: @reuns, thank you very much, though.

Comment: Ok asking what is $L$ is simple, clear, you make some progress. $L$ is a lattice, a subset of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ of the form $L = \{n \vec{u}+m \vec{v}, (n,m) \in \mathbb{Z}^2\}$ and with $\vec{u},\vec{v}$ not colinears. So $L$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ and $\mathbb{Z}^2/L$ is the quotient group, a finite abelian group. The big problem of lattices is that there are many ways to change $\vec{u},\vec{v}$ without changing the lattice they generate.

Comment: @reuns, Thanks! So, how $ad=n$ implies $|\mathbb{Z}^2/L|=n$? - also, $L=\mathbb{Z}.(a,b) \oplus \mathbb{Z}.(0,d)$ can generally be lattice as a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z^2}$ if $b=0$?

Comment: What is the surface of the [parallelogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_torus) defined by $(a,b),(0,d)$ ?

Comment: @reuns, yes I got it. It doesn't have to be b=0. It still is lattice. So ad=n is the area of a generator of lattice. So that's why $|\mathbb{Z}^2/L|=n$?